# AWS beanstalk: Why settings reset when beanstalk servers are restarted, however WAR deployement work fine with the changes

Tags: gzip, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-beanstalk

After lots of struggles, I identified how to enable gzip compression on my aws beanstalk Java-tomcat environment

In war file I have instructions to overwrite this file which have few added file types for compression e.g: text/html

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/01_gzip.conf
```

It works fine but after few days it just reset itself, I am not sure what is causing this?